# Executable Python Program with Multiple Functions (MacOS)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I would like to seek advise regarding Python.

I created a main.py using Python that calls multiple functions, which are located in separate python script files. I'd like to create executable files in MacOS and I found this command:

```
chmod +x main.py
```

However, since main.py calls another function, I can't run as it gave me error. Kindly advise how to link those function scripts into the main script.

Thanks.

Comment: "I can't run as it gave me error". What was the error?

Comment: hummm, *from script1 import function1*   then *function1()*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the issue is and since there isn't a lot of detail I'm going to start from the beginning:

The command `chmod +x main.py` is indicating to your system that the file `main.py` is an executable file.  Since `main.py` isn't a program that can be executed, you are going to have to tell OSX how to run this script you have created.  This is where the shebang comes in [Shebang (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

At the top of your script you are going to need to put the following line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This will tell your computer to pass your `main.py` script to python for execution.

Now onto the import stuff.  Python is going to look in the following locations when you use the `import` statement [see the python docs for more info](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
>
> `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`).
>
> The installation-dependent default.

So if you had a module `foo.py` with a function `bar` and place `foo.py` in the same directory as `main.py`, you can do the following in your `main.py` script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import foo
foo.bar() <-- this will run the bar function defined in foo.py
```

Alternatively you could do the following in main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from foo import bar
bar() <-- this will run the bar function defined in foo.py
```